# Getting Process ID of started process using SSH2 - phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, libssh2, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib, Net_SSH2.

I need to get the process ID of the server/process that is started by this command.

```
echo $ssh->exec('java -Xmx256M -Xms32M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui');
```

This is so i can store it and be able to kill it via a PHP script at anytime.

Comment: [Check this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
echo $ssh->exec('java -Xmx256M -Xms32M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this would work if you want to track PID of particular command after its execution.

```
$cmd = 'java -Xmx256M -Xms32M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui';
$pid = $ssh->exec('echo `ps aux | grep -F "' . $cmd . '" | grep -v -F "grep" | awk \'{ print $2 }\'`');
echo $pid;
```

To Kill same:

```
$ssh->exec("kill -9 $pid");
```